# Azure AVD connectivity to on-premises network without outbound internet

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-network

Can we disable outbound internet from azure virtual desktop(VM) running remoteApp streaming and still use azure site-to-site vpn connectivity to connect AVD to on-premises network?! Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable Outbound Internet Connectivity from azure virtual desktop (VM)

***Go to azure portal -> virtual machine -> Networking -> outbound port rule -> add outbound port rule***

[image]

In adding outbound security rule check the below snip ***Source port ranges -> destination -> destination port -> priority ->Name -> Add.*** change as according:

[image]

Once completed you will see the name of rule ***Denyinternet*** and *Go to overview -> connect ->RDP -> download RDP file -> connect -> Open Internet Explorer*

***You should not get the page displayed. It ensures Internet Connectivity is disabled now.***

Again, you want access internet delete the inbound rule and refresh page it will appear.